# Find theta given point on circle

Tags: circles, rotations, angle

I am having trouble visualizing and understanding how you might obtain an angle given a point on a circle. I have a $(x, y)$ point where the values range between $0,1$ for both $x,y$. How would I calculate the angle theta?

My confusion comes from a piece of code which is taking a random point and calculating theta and then using this theta to produce a rotation matrix to rotate a given direction.

I have a disk which is divided into $N$ directions. In this instance we have divided into $8$.
[image]

A single direction angle can be obtained by looping through the amount of directions and doing $ i * disk$ as shown in the code below. This will be the direction we would like to rotate. Below is implementation in GLSL

```
// Rotate direction
vec2 RotateDirectionAngle(vec2 direction, vec2 noise)
{
    float theta = noise.y * (2.0 * PI);
    float costheta = cos(theta);
    float sintheta = sin(theta);
    mat2 rotationMatrix = mat2(vec2(costheta, -sintheta), vec2(sintheta, costheta));

    return rotationMatrix * direction;
} 

int directions = 8;
disk = 2 * pi / directions

for(int i = 0; i < directions; i++)
{
    float samplingDirectionAngle = i * disk;
    vec2 rotatedDirection = RotateDirectionAngle(vec2(cos(samplingDirectionAngle), sin(samplingDirectionAngle)), noise.xy);
    
}
```

Sorry if this question is super basic but I'm finding it hard to visualize the calculations. Would appreciate any insight to help me better understand

Comment: You didn't give us engough information: in order to define an angle you need two lines, if your point gives us on line, which is the second line ? Where is the $\theta = 0$ ?

Comment: And in what language is written your code ?

Comment: @EmileCouzin Thanks for the reply! Sorry, I have provided further information and updated the post :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many languages, this is implemented as the atan2 function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2. Note that the arguments are swapped: `atan2(y, x)` returns the angle between the positive $x$ axis and the half line joining $(0,0)$ to $(x, y)$.

Mathematically, you can also use these formulas
\begin{equation}
r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\qquad \theta = 2 \arctan\left(\frac{y}{r + x}\right) \quad\text{if }x\not= -r
\end{equation}
and $\theta=\pi$ when $x = -r$. This formula gives an angle in the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$.

It is not necessary to compute the angle to get the rotation matrix because $\cos\theta = \frac{x}{r}$ and $\sin\theta = \frac{y}{r}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If the radius is $1$. I can just do `cos(noise.x/1)` and `sin(noise.y/1)` to compute the rotation matrix?

Comment: If the radius is 1, the rotation matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}x & - y\\ y & x\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Ah ok, I see. What is $r$ meant to calculate in the above equations?

Comment: $r$ is the distance between the point $(0, 0)$ and the point $(x, y)$. It appears in the formula giving $\theta$. The rotation matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}x/r & -y/r \\ y/r & x/r\end{pmatrix}$. The point $(x/r, y/r)$ is always on the unit circle (unless $(x, y ) = (0,0)$)

Comment: Ah ok, think that makes sense but as you mentioned before, if the circle is a unit circle, we do not need to do $x/r$ we can just leave it as $x$?

Comment: Indeed, when $r=1$ we have $x/r = x$.

Answer (score 0):

On the circle below, you have $A \equiv (x, y), \ B \equiv (0, 0), \ C \equiv (x, 0)$:

[image: Circle on geogebra]

You see the triangle $ABC$ is a right triangle since $\hat{ACB} = 90$°. You have thus those relations:
\begin{equation}
\sin \theta := \frac{|AC|}{|AB|}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\cos \theta := \frac{|BC|}{|AB|}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tan \theta := \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{|AC|}{|BC|} = \frac{y}{x}
\end{equation}
Your angle $\theta$ is thus:
\begin{equation}
\theta = \arctan{\left( \frac{y}{x} \right)} \ (x \neq 0)
\end{equation}
for $x = 0, \theta = 90$°.

Comment: The drawback of this formula is that it works only when $x>0$.